# Creating dynamic meta tags in a laravel application

Tags: php, laravel, dynamic, tags, laravel-blade

I am trying to implement dynamic meta tags in my laravel app. I have a head.blade.php file in which i have all the code that goes in head. This is what i have been doing, i have created a file called meta-conf.php under pages folder, the head.blade.php contains -

```
@if(Route::currentRouteName() != false) 
{{
    $page = Route::currentRouteName();
}}
    @include('pages.meta-conf');
{{
    $title = $meta[$page]['title'];
    $keywords = $meta[$page]['keywords'];
    $description = $meta[$page]['description'];
}}
@else
{{
   $title = "akademe";
   $keywords = "";
   $description = "Quickly find near by courses";
}}
@endif
```

The meta-conf.php contains -

```
<?php

$meta['index']['title'] = "Home";
$meta['index']['keywords'] = "explore, learn, repeat, education, register, institute, courses";
$meta['index']['description'] = "Quickly find near by courses";
```

Now its throwing me an error "Undefined variable: meta ". I have included the meta-conf.php file which contains the $meta array defined as you can see above. Dunno what is causing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do instead of what you're doing is this:

- Add the title, keywords and description as public variables to your base Controller (`app/Http/Controllers/Controller.php`)
- Initialise the variables on the Controller constructor and set the "default" values
- From your controllers (Courses, Search, etc.) set the specific values for each page
- Implement a "renderPage" method on your base Controller so that you can pass a view and parameters from your controllers
- Render method will load the requested view and pass the parameters *and* your meta tag variables
- Update your `head.blade.php` to use your meta variables

I haven't tested any of the above but thinking something like that should work :)